# How can I apply a LADSPA plugin to a PulseAudio stream?

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to apply a LADSPA plugin to everything that streams through the default PulseAudio sink. How should I set this up?

Comment: @Takkat what about modules with more inputs or ports like [TAP Stereo Echo](http://tap-plugins.sourceforge.net/ladspa/echo.html)? I can't get it to work with: `load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=echo master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo plugin=tap_echo label=tap_echo control=100,0,100,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding a LADSPA plugin to pulseaudio is done with **module-ladspa-sink**.

We install this module as an output sink where we can define the processing module and are able to send the processed signal to this newly created sink.

#### Load the LADSPA module:

This module can be loaded at runtime with:

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=<yourname> master=<sinkname> plugin=<plugin> label=<label> control=<option1>,<option2>,[...]
```

The name of the master sink can be read with the following command:

```
 pacmd list-sinks
```

Give a name for the processed sink as it will appear in the output list in `sink_name`. All further options depend on the plugin we use (see example below).

To apply the LADSPA processor we choose the output sink from *"Sound Settings..."* and can now listen to the processed stream. Control options can not be altered at runtime.

#### Unload the LADSPA module:

We  will have to unload the module and load it again for different options. To find the module index for unloading we may issue:

```
 pacmd list-modules
```

To unload a module we either restart the sound server with `pulseaudio -k` or we unload the module with it's index number `#`:

```
pacmd unload-module <#>
```

See also the [reference wiki from pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index47h3).

#### Load LADSPA module at startup:

After having found the appropriate options we may want to run it per default. This can be done by including it to the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` configuration file to be loaded by the daemon on startup:

```
.ifexists module-ladspa-sink.so
.nofail
load-module module-ladspa-sink <options>
.fail
.endif
```

---

#### Example:

This is an example of one special case to give you an idea on how to do it. In this example we want to apply a pitch shift to our sound output using the unfortunately no longer active TAP-plugin **tap_pitch** ([tap-plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tap-plugins) [image: Install tap-plugins]). For this plugin the additional options needed for loading to Pulse Audio are the following:

```
plugin=tap_pitch # as from /usr/lib/ladspa/ without .so
label=tap_pitch  # defines which label of a plugin to use
```

To find the appropriate control options we may still find the plugin documentation in a web archive (previous URL: [TAP plugin pitch shifter](http://tap-plugins.sourceforge.net/ladspa/pitch.html)). There we find a nice table of four relevant controls we have to apply in the `control=` command:

```
control=<semitone>,<rate>,<dry>,<wet>
```

Leaving an option empty will use the default in this case.

Thus the following command will apply a pitch shift of one octave downward from my master sink `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo` (replace with your sink) to the output sink `ladspa_out` with a semitone shift of `-12`, that is a rate shift of `-50`%, and with a dry (unprocessed) mixer level of `-90`dB, and a wet (processed) level of `0`dB.

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_out master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo plugin=tap_pitch label=tap_pitch control=-12,-50,-90,0
```

For some plugins the documentation may be not be complete, or appropriate setting will need quite some experimenting until they are right.

Comment: How can I apply one of these filters (made from pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink *) to my microphone input? So I can run a system wide filter and it applies to Mumble, Teamspeak, Skype, Games. I want other people to here the filtered input, it's not for myself (only).

Comment: @braindamage can't test this here (no microphone) but try with a duplex profile for the master sink, or try with <name_of_source>.monitor as the master.

Comment: your link to the plugin documentation is a 404 error.

Comment: @DBear thank you for the notice. TAP are no longer developed, the souce is hosted on GitHUb: https://github.com/tomszilagyi/tap-plugins but the documetation sadly appears to be gone (try with WayBackMachine).