# How can I modify the pitch of my audio output?

Tags: sound, output

I would like to modify the pitch of my audio output.

I know you can use software such as PlayItSlowly to listen to an audio file and alter the pitch in the process, but what I am looking for is a way to modify the pitch just as I do with the volume.

I can do it on Windows with Realtek's sound manager, so I guess there must be a way to do it on Linux as well.

Comment: If there is no way to do it in Linux you can thank Realtek and/or the OEM of your hardware for dropping the ball and not supporting their own hardware in Linux.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/195077/590937

Comment: @Sumit - Did you have a chance of testing what was proposed?

Answer (score 0):

Install ALSA equalizer plugin:

`sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugin-equal`

Prepare your .asoundrs file, so that ALSA will know about the plugin:

`gedit .asoundrc`

Paste inside it (or append at the end, if it already contains some data):

```
ctl.equal {
   type equal;
}

pcm.plugequal {
    type equal;
   slave.pcm "plughw:0,0";
}

pcm.equal{
    type plug;
    slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

Save the file and exit.

Next, reload ALSA:

`sudo alsa force-reload`

Your equalizer should be set-up. To use it, run

`alsamixer -D equal`

TADA! Your alsamixer will now behave as an equalizer, instead of adjusting volumes. Hope this helps!

Comment: this is an equalizer, not a pitch changer. how is this helpful in regards to OPs question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.
Many of them require [Soundtouch](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/soundtouch/index.html), which is a plugin from the [Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gi-index.html) set "bad".
Run

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

I wouldn't know which of the options listed below do not satisfy your requirement "just as I do with the volume", and why (e.g., playitslowly).

### Sound stretch

[Soundstretch](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/soundstretch.1.html) seems to do the trick.

> SoundStretch  is  a  simple  command-line  application  that  can
> change tempo, pitch and playback rates of WAV sound files. This
> program is intended primarily to  demonstrate  howthe  "SoundTouch"
> library can be used to process sound in your own program, but it can
> as well be used for processing sound files.

Usage:

```
soundstretch infile.wav outfile.wav [options]
```

Options:

```
...
-pitch=n Change the sound pitch by n semitones (n = -60.0 .. + 60.0 semitones)
...
```

### Play it slowly

`playitslowly` ([official documentation](https://github.com/jwagner/playitslowly)) is a GUI, which also provides for a change in pitch. See also [here](https://www.justkeepdistance.com/change-pitch-speed-and-fine-pitch-easily-in-ubuntu/).

[image]

### ffmpeg

Apparently, `ffmpeg` can also be [used to change pitch](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292532&p=13346539#post13346539).

### Audacity

[Same](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292532&p=13346988#post13346988) as with ffmpeg.

### PitchBox

See [official info](https://www.pitchtech.ch/PitchBox/).

### Others

There may be other options associated with different pieces of [LADSPA](https://www.ladspa.org/) software.

**Related**:

1. [How can I apply a LADSPA plugin to a PulseAudio stream?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream)

Comment: How does this change the pitch of sound output?

Comment: @svin83 - I don't understand your question. The methods provided do exactly that. If you are asking about the details of the implementation at the programming level, or even at the hardware level, I don't know, and I don't think the OP is interested either. But if you mean that you don't see this answers the question, I suggest you simply try what is posted. I did it, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I know that the output stream is a file you can pipe output to, but most users don't know that just about every device API in Linux is a file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two programs that I know of that can do this. One is called [rubberband](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/rubberband-cli_1.8.2-1build1_arm64.deb.html). You can also see the manual page [here](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/RUBBERBAND/). It is a time and pitch shifter. These two tools go hand in hand, as shifting the pitch will let you speed up the tempo without turning the result into a chipmunks track.

You can get `rubberband` from apt. It also has a command-line interface available with `rubberband-cli`.

The other is [zita-retune](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/zita-resampler_1.6.2-1_amd64.deb.html). It is available on apt as well. It exposes the command [zretune](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/zita-retune.1.html), which does the same as above through resampling. The `zita library` is very popular among Linux audio community, and has just about any type of pro-audio software tool there is.

I got both of them in the Ubuntu Studio Tools Installer kit. It is an apt package (namely `ubuntustudio-installer`) that gives you all of the sound design tools that come with `studio`, including the `lowlatency` kernel, but installs them in a way where they seem more like an added feature to the standard ubuntu flavor and not so much like a different flavor altogether. I personally just load the `lowlatency` kernel, when I need it, and stick with `generic` the rest of the time, as the `lowlatency` doesn't handle multiple monitors very well.

Answer (score -3):

Use the alsa-mixer

Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer alsamixergui libasound2-plugin-equal alsa-utils`

[image]

Comment: I have tried really hard to understand what you meant, but I don't see where alsa-mixer does something else than adjusting volumes ...