# Alsa equalizer for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, equalizer

How do you get the Alsa equalizer in Ubuntu 16.04? Is it just installing `libasound2-plugin-equal` that is required? What is `libasound2-plugin-equal`?

Thank you.

Comment: Look [About this plugin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libasound2-plugin-equal). That's a plugin that enable your alsamixer to open a equalizer. After installing it, run `alsamixer` at terminal session to check it.

Comment: You could see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120284/how-can-i-modify-the-pitch-of-my-audio-output). I'm interested in it. I'll try it later!

Comment: If `libasound2-plugin-equal` is installed, and the instructions for the configuration file are added into .asoundrc and `alsamixer -D equal` is opened, what might cause the equalizer settings from making any difference in audio levels? I have come across this [to disable pulseaudio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/alsaequal-runs-but-sliders-do-not-seem-to-affect-audio). Though it appears if pulseaudio is disabled then no audio works. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I did same procedures, and got same results. It seems we must look for another equalizer for alsa.