# Is there any dsp solution for ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm searching for a Audio DSP solution for ubuntu. I want to have the possibility to set some high pass and low pass filter to my 5.1 outputs. Low pass for the LFE and high pass for surround and center for instance.
I have "correctly" set up my installation and can change the volume on each channels but

- Changing the output on some channels will also change the overall output on others (it has probably something to do with
  upmixing??)
- I didn't find anything to set a high or low pass filter on one specific channel.

Until now I used the pulse equalizer and it does it's job but apply the filters on all channels at the same time. Is there any way to get this? 
I'm surprised that there is no nice solution to tweak sound on linux.
Hope someone can help me there :)

Comment: Would an LADSPA filter (e.g. of the [Steve Harris' set](http://plugin.org.uk/ladspa-swh/docs/ladspa-swh.html))  suit your needs? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/194281/apply-ladspa-filter-to-only-one-channel-of-multichannel-output-with-alsa-and-pul and http://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream for how to use them.

Comment: Hi Takkat,
Yes, this seems to be the right tool. I will use my WE to get this straight. Thanks for the head up!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [lmms](https://lmms.io/). I'm not that professional in case of Audio, but I think this should help.

[image]

To install run the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install lmms
```

Comment: Thanks, Isn't this software for producer? I want only to modify my outputs on each channels while playing music or watching a video on my ubuntu.
Can this software do that?

Comment: From what I've read about yes, but just take a look at their site and check, I'm not that professional in multimedia, but i think yes

Comment: Thanks Maythux. I will dig that and come back if it works :) Have a nice day!

Comment: welcome, have a nice time

Comment: Unfortunately I will have to play with the LADSPA solution. This does'nt work for me :(
Thanks anyway for the help!