# Real time audio manipulation program

Tags: audacity, ardour

What I'd like to do is play back audio files (currently mp3, but I'd convert them if I had to), and perform basic audio manipulation on them, equalization, panning etc, and to be able to manipulate the parameters as the media were playing.

In some sense what I want is audacity to support manipulation of its filter plugins while the media are playing, but it doesn't seem to support this.  ardour does allow this, but I'd like to know if there is something a litter lighter-weight and less complicated.

So, which ubuntu packages provide this type of functionality.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the repository for the keyword "LADSPA", you will find a LOT of tools (and players) there that have support for LADSPA

LADSPA is an audio plugin framework for realtime manipulation of sound.
site: http://www.ladspa.org

One player that might be of interest is "aqualung"