# Sound morphing software

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, skype, microphone

I need real-time sound morphing software for linux, but I can't find anything. Something ib Ubuntu software center didn't started, and astersk-voicechanger is uninstallable. In windows there is a bunch of such a software, but i think wining them won't give any result. Suggest such kind of app if you know

Comment: Real time sound processing can be done using [LADSPA filters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream).