# Updated audio mixer for 14.04+

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, noise

Is there any advanced audio mixer where I can have more control of my microphones (audio input)?

There's almost no options on alsamixer and the default pulseaudio mixer. Also, I can only see stereo options for my microphone (digital stereo, normal stereo, ...). I would like to change things like frequency, add noise cancellation and maybe other filters at the OS level.

I'm picking up too much background noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete recording, editing, and audio mixer software is [Ardour](https://ardour.org/). This software is based on Jack rather than PulseAudio sound server.

#### [Ardour](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ardour) [image: Install ardour]

can be installed from the Software Center but it will likely better be integrated in the [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) flavour of Ubuntu.

If it is only a single or few LADSPA plugins we can also integrate them to the default Pulseaudio server:

- [How can I apply a LADSPA plugin to a PulseAudio stream?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream)

For editing (but not for real-time effects) we may have a look at [Audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity) [image: Install audacity] which also nicely integrates additionally installed LADSPA plugins.