# default volume level for a new or unknown stream

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

If i am playing a video or audio stream in my internet browser, the volume of this stream is set to 100 percent in pulseaudio. This is way too loud. I can reduce the volume manually, but i like to have it automatically.

Is there a way to set the default volume level for a new or unknown stream in pulseaudio?

Comment: Open ***pulse audio*** make sure you tick ***EQ Enabled*** and ***Keep Settings*** open `audio setting -> output` make sure to check **`LADSPA Plugin`**  it's installed by default with pulse audio ubuntu 16.04 LTS for more customize or if you not found  **`LADSPA Plugin`** check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream for different solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content

Comment: @MohamedSlama: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. If you post it as an answer, i would mark it as accepted. PS: I am using Arch Linux. Installing **pulseaudio-equalizer-ladspa** and **pulseaudio-equalizer** in combination with your instruction of checking **EQ Enabled** and **Keep Settings** were doing the trick. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open ***pulse audio*** make sure you tick ***EQ Enabled*** and ***Keep Settings***.
2. Open ***audio setting -> output*** make sure to chose `LADSPA Plugin` (installed by default with pulse audio ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
3. For more customize or if you not found LADSPA Plugin check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream).