# Is there a program out there that will adjust audio volume to a certain level system wide?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, multimedia

Is there a program out there that will adjust audio volume to a certain level system wide?

I have a HTPC and its driving me nuts with different apps playing audio at different levels.  XMBC plays at one volume, VLC another, and system sounds yet another...  Some sounds can barely be heard, but when turning them up, other apps are deafeningly loud.

Is there something that can normalize the volume across everything?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content

Answer (score 0):

We can adjust default output device, and volume level for an application by installing and running [**pavucontrol**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol]:

[image]
<sup>here shown in XFCE</sup>