# Is there a way to have Clementine normalize my music?

Tags: music, clementine

I've got two related music files/albums.
However they are at different volumes.

Any Idea as to how to fix this?

I have tried going into preferences--->playback and hitting replay gain however that seemed to have no effect.

Comment: At the end of the day, your sound quality is only as good as the original file. Personally I use ffmpeg to try to adjust volume with mixed results. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20change%20audio%20volume%20up-down%20with%20FFmpeg

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/normalize-audio.1.html

Comment: If you want a specific answer you need to be more specific with your question. What format are your music files in? (container, codec for example)

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/246242/how-to-normalize-sound-in-mp3-files

Comment: You could also check into the program normalize-audio which you can get with `sudo apt-get install normalize-audio`

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `Replay Gain` option your music files need appropriate metadata. Clementine cannot create it but you can use external tools, e.g., http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/.