# Normalize all audio files before copying to an iPod

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, music, ipod

I know [how to normalize a song to 100%](https://askubuntu.com/a/246266/148451), but I'd like this to happen automatically before copying the files on my iPod, via Rhythmbox.

So, I imagine a process like this:

- create my own playlist
- when clicking *Sync* button, the songs will be copied in a temp directory
- they will be normalized to 100% there
- finally they will be copied to my iPod

Is there a plugin for that? How can I do this?

---

I want this, because the max volume for iPods is pretty low.

Comment: There is a way to monitor a special folder and to automatically run a script (f.i. normalize with mp3gain) when a file is created in. Not sure it is what you want: Interested ?

Comment: Well, that should be very simple. But I would really like a plugin that does this job automatically when trying to copy songs on iPod.

Comment: @laugeo Even that would be helpful. It will be a starter point. Can you add it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **inotify** which is a folder monitoring software: it launch a command when a file is created .
Here, it will  launch mp3gain . To set up  :

1. Install

`sudo apt-get install inotify-tools  incron mp3gain`

2. edit incron.allow

`sudo gedit /etc/incron.allow`
then add your username , save , you may 
reboot  (not sure but ...)

3. Choose or create a folder where sound files  will be copied and then normalized
   (Here I create a new folder "normalize" in my home dir. but you may  use existing folder be on your usb device,
   something like  /media/ipod/music)

> > mkdir ~/normalize

4. Run `incrontab -e`   and  copy  this line in the editor (replace 2 "username" with your login ) :
   `/home/username/normalize IN_CREATE /home/username/normalize.bash $@/$#`
   Save and close editor .
   This  set the monitored folder  and  the command executed when a file is created in (command is normalize.bash ).

*(If you have problem with default editor , you can change it to pico (gedit don't work for me)  : Run this before `incrontab -e`  :
`export EDITOR=pico` 
)*

5. Create a new file normalize.bash containing this :

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> PATH1=/home/username/normalize    
> echo "***********************************************************"  >> ~/normalize.log
>  date >> ~/normalize.log   
> #get extension to exit on TMP files
> filename=$(basename "$1")
> extension="${filename##*.}"   
> if [[ "$extension" = "TMP" ]]
>  then
> echo TMP exit>> ~/normalize.log
>  exit
>  fi   
> # do normalize
> /usr/bin/mp3gain -c -r "$1"   >> ~/normalize.log   
> #END
> ```

In second line change PATH1 to the previously created/existing folder.
Save as normalize.bash in your home.

Now, when a file is created in the folder "normalize", mp3gain will run 
(actions are logged in normalized.log file in home dir)

Comment: +1, maybe someone will use this for a creating a Rhythmbox plugin.