# Rhythmbox: How to normalize song volumes?

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, mp3-player

When putting songs on a mp3 player with Rhythmbox it's not very convenient to have different volumes for songs. Is there a solution which automatically sets same volumes (I have seen this in other players)?

I'm looking for a plugin.

Comment: A solution involving changing the files: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246242/how-to-normalize-sound-in-mp3-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically adjust the volume based on content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content)

Comment: These are not for rhythmbox. I'm looking for something (a plugin inside rhythmbox).

Answer (score 0):

There is a replaygain plugin in rhythmbox:

Go to Tools >> plugins, check **ReplayGain**

(be sure to have the package `rhythmbox-plugins` installed)