# Switch between headphone and speaker automatically?

Tags: sound, 17.04, speakers, output

I'am using ubuntu 17.04.

When I connect my headphones I need to manually switch my sound output in the  settings from speakers to headphones. After removing my headphones I need to manually switch back to the speaker.

How can this be done automatically?

Comment: I have the same problem every time I need to switch from PulseAudio. have you figured out the problem so far?

Comment: Also have the same problem on Ubuntu 19.10: I connect the headphones and Ubuntu still uses the HDMI source from a screen. Would be nice to have an automatic switch like Windows or Android does

Comment: To switch between outputs use [this command/custom shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231226/349837). To automatically switch to HDMI check [here on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Automatically_switch_audio_to_HDMI)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is A BEST solution to this, it's up to personal preference.

What I love to do is have my usb headphone and 5.1 surround sound system plugged in at the same time.

To switch from one to the other, say sound-system to headphones, I hit the power button on my sound system to trun it off and scroll the volume knob on my usb headset to turn it on (system volume is on 70% so 100% on the headset is a fine tuned fit).

[Guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/78179/307184).

Note : once "Add virtual output device for simultaneous output on all sound cards" is enabled, reboot then continue the rest of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto terminal
2. simply type *alsamixer*
3. if you have already it in your system then you must see several bar indicating sound levels
4. by clicking right arrow goto **Front bar** & by down arrow to make it 00
5. thats it & it worked on my intel driven **PC.**
   hope it might help you.

[image]