# Ubuntu 20.04 Not Detecting Audio Jack Headset Automatically on ASUS TUF Gaming FX505GD

Tags: sound, headset, audio-jack

As the title says, my laptop can't detect the headset automatically. Every time I plug or unplug a headset, I have to switch the output device manually from Settings -> Output Device dropdown to make it work.

Before, my headset still works even if I forget to switch the output device from "speaker" to "headphone", but both of the headset and speaker will play sounds. But after trying one of the solutions below (I don't know which one), now the headset won't work at all.

If I forget to switch the output device from "headphone" to "speaker" after I unplug the headset, the speaker won't play any sounds. It's always been like that since the first time I installed Ubuntu on my ASUS.

I dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10. In windows 10, the autodetection works perfectly so I don't think there's something wrong with my audio jack. I also don't think anything wrong with the headset, because the autodetection works perfectly on my Dell Inspiron 3180 (also run on Ubuntu 20.04).

Some link for solutions that I've tried but failed:

1. [Headset undetected when plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184901/headset-undetected-when-plugged-in)
2. [Sound output doesn't change automatically after connecting to Bluetooth headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086060/sound-output-doesnt-change-automatically-after-connecting-to-bluetooth-headset)
3. [Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)
4. [Headphones not detected if plugged in before boot Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118991/headphones-not-detected-if-plugged-in-before-boot-ubuntu-18-04)
5. [Automatically change Sound Input Output device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158241/automatically-change-sound-input-output-device)
6. [Switch between headphone and speaker automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914385/switch-between-headphone-and-speaker-automatically)

Some important things that I think need to be noted:

1. I've tried to re-installed my Ubuntu.
2. I installed my Ubuntu on my ASUS and Dell the same way (minimal installation). The difference is, on my ASUS I dual-booted it alongside Windows 10, while on my Dell I also installed Lubuntu and Xubuntu. Maybe this will give hints on why the detection works on my Dell.
3. On my Dell, I get a notification in which I can select what type of device (headset/headphone/microphone) that I plug (usually my headset), but on my Asus, nothing shows. (I can't post images as my rep is below 10, so here's the link to the notification pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNhGG.jpg)

If you need some additional, I'll gladly provide more.