# Headphones and speakers at the same time on my Thinkpad

Tags: sound, alsa, 19.04, thinkpad, headphones

like the title says, I can't seem to auto-mute the speakers if I plug in my headphones. I've checked in alsamixer but it doesn't even have a headphones section and I've tried the workaround posted here a couple of years ago adding the lines

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-1 enable_msi=1
```

in the alsa-base.conf file but it didn't work.

Comment: This answer will probably work with a little tweaking: https://askubuntu.com/questions/712517/how-to-switch-between-headphones-and-speakers-without-unplugging-headphones/1005980#1005980

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I tried your tip but I can't seem to store via alsactl. If you look into the syslogs, it also says Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
Not sure what to do now.