# No sound out of laptop speakers with Alder Lake audio controller

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel

I have an HP Envy x360 15-ew0023dx that I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on, and the speakers do not play audio at all. Headphones work if plugged in. The command `lspci` shows `00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)`.

I've seen a million posts about Alder Lake audio not working right on various Linux distributions, but all the ideas I've seen either don't fix the problem or are too complicated for me to even attempt.

I tried installing the latest mainline kernel 6.1.11, seeing that some issues with Intel audio were fixed in later kernels, but it didn't help.

I've been trying to install sof-firmware-signed 2.2.4. I installed the .deb file, but I'm not sure if it worked. Is this line in `lspci` supposed to change to `sof-firmware-signed` for the audio controller: `Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl`?

Does anyone have any suggestions for how this could be fixed? Or possibly a Linux distribution that audio is likely to work on? I like Ubuntu and have never tried another, but I'm willing to.

[image]

Edit: While I no longer have this laptop (partly because of this issue), I'll add links to two bug reports related to the issue, for others' reference:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216311
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1914881

Comment: Have checked your output device in settings/sound?

Comment: I added a picture. It seems like everything is working there. The output device bars show bars for loudness when there is a video playing, but there is no sound. Using `Test` on headphones works, but not on speakers. And there are no other options under `Output Devices`.

Comment: I recommend running - `mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old` and `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` This is a safe and simple way to reset audio settings.

Comment: @stumblebee I did that and then restarted. No change.

Comment: Go back to output device in settings/sound and recheck. if that is all set correctly, Run `alsamixer` and check settings there. You will need to use up and down arrow keys to maneuver around and adjust settings. Press <ESC> to exit the program.

Comment: @stumblebee It looks like everything is turned up in playback. The sound card is `sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp  HP-HPENVYx3602_in_1Laptop15_ew0xxx-Type1ProductConfigId-8A29`

Comment: Since the headphones are working, as silly as it may sound, I have to ask if you are trying to use the external speakers while your headphones are plugged in? If not, Here is a Intel sound configuration tool that may help - https://askubuntu.com/a/1005967/767056

Comment: No, they weren't plugged in. I couldn't get that tool to do anything without giving errors. I did find this post which says it has a solution for the exact problem and model of computer I have, by installing a kernel patch? I guess I have to figure out how to do that. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722205/hp-envy-x360-2022-ryzen-edition-speakers-not-working

Comment: The patch from the previous comment doesn't seem to fix it. Maybe because the laptops aren't exactly the same model number.

Comment: While I no longer have this laptop (partly because of this issue), I'll add links to two bug reports related to the issue, for others' reference: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216311 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1914881