# Why won't my laptop speakers work Ubuntu 22.04.2?

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, speakers

I am unfamiliar with how to troubleshoot audio, however, I can tell you the following:

1. My headphone jack works, audio goes through
2. The "output device" under Settings->Sound is listed as "Speaker - sof-hda-dsp"
3. I have tried using Ubuntu 20.04 all the way up to 22.10 and the results were consistent i.e. speakers never worked

There is a very similar post here but I could not find a solution:
[No sound out of laptop speakers with Alder Lake audio controller](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454834/no-sound-out-of-laptop-speakers-with-alder-lake-audio-controller)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please try bootoption `snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1`  Found here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci

Comment: Hi @nobody thanks for the reply, I haven't tried that solution, however, that solution makes the microphone stop working from what I read. Any other alternative? I tried installing sof binaries from the github repo.

Comment: Also tried sudo apt install firmware-sof-signed but it said:
firmware-sof-signed is already the newest version (2.0-1ubuntu4.1).
firmware-sof-signed set to manually installed.

Comment: I tried adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1" to my /etc/default/grub and now in the settings->sound it refers to the output device as "Speakers - Built-in audio", however, the audio still does not work. The blue bar does go up indicating there is output to that device, however, nothing audible at all. Furthermore, the input device (microphone) is no longer being detected.

Comment: Another attempt, added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0" instead of the above, still same result: no audio, no input device detected, but referring to the output device as "Speakers - built-in audio"

Comment: There should be a button in the sound settings that lets you test the speakers. I know they don't work, but can you try using that test feature to see if it even tries to play audio or if it gets stuck while trying? That might give us a hint.

Comment: It does try to play audio, and the "bar" indicating the output goes up, but nothing comes out. It does not get stuck while trying.

Comment: Also, just so that I know I'm not going crazy, I fresh installed Windows 11 just now, it automatically picked up the audio drivers from Windows update and it works, so the device is functioning.