# Headset microphone not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am Trying to use my 3.5mm jack headset with **ubuntu 22.04** on an acer device, However the microphone doesn't work (It Works as an output device only!), I Overdrived pin 0x18 and pin 0x19 to microphone in **hdajackretask** (It produces some errors: Device or resource busy, but it works), Now it asks me everytime I plug in my headset whether the device is a headphone, headset, microphone, I selected headset and now i have 2 microphones: **Microphone 1 -Built-In
Audio**, and **Microphone 2 -Built-In Audio**, And they both Don't work(The built-In mic was previously working but with bad quality), This is Driving me Crazy!, NOTE: one mic is producing noise, just noise and the other is completly silent

-Edit:

```
aplay -l

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

NOTE: Please note that I am using a 2 jack headset with an adapter,Because my laptop only has one jack port

Comment: Please run both `aplay -l` and `lsb_release -a` then [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1502151/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: @stumblebee should I switch to pipewire?

Comment: `hdajackretask` usually works since most HDA Intel soundcards are to some degree retaskable, It may be worth taking a look at [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1005967/767056). I don't know if switching to pipewire will help since I dont know much about it.

Comment: This, but I had Audio -> Microphone disabled in my Bios settings.