# Normalize sound while watching youtube videos

Tags: sound

Is there a program/way to normalize sound levels so it won't go beyond a certain defined level ?

Video/Music sounds are inconsistent in their levels and each time there is a need to change the sound level of the system to adjust for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here: [Automatically adjust the volume based on content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content)

Using this method you can load pulse modules (effects) and connect them to your default output sink. This doesn't only affect YouTube videos, but all sound outputted by your computer. However, you can easily switch back and forth between the different output sinks.