# Compressor/Limiter for master volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

looking for something that makes the volume of youtube, netflix, etc. behave in such a way that when watching an action movie the dialog becomes very loud and the explosions, machine guns, etc. sound low (same level as the dialog) so I don't wake up my roommates and don't have to turn the volume up when there's dialog and turn the volume down when loud stuff goes on, basically a Compressor/Limiter on the master volume, is there such thing?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content

Answer (score 1):

You can use PulseEffects for this purpose:

The following commands will install PulseEffects on your computer. As you are adding a PPA, you should also know how to remove that PPA.

First, install the program for (eventual) PPA removal:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

Secondly, add the PPA to your system, do an APT update, and then install PulseEffects

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y pulseeffects
```

Finally, should you need to remove PulseEffects:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects
```

Comment: You are right you can use PulseEffectsfor this, but you don't say how (which settings and which values).

Comment: @WiR3D This is true, but learning about the qualities of sound production may be a bit beyond the scope of AskUbuntu.  I've found during recording sessions, that the value used for compression and limiting depend upon a wide range of factors - from the audio source to the 'enthusiasm' of the performer being miked, the processing equipment in the middle and the output devices and their response to a given set of sounds...

Comment: Is it called easyeffects nowaways? https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects

Comment: @danger89 It could be - I don't often listen to music on my computer, but over bluetooth on my harley instead.