# Audio normalization on output - save my speakers and headphones!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Is there a program or command line setting that will boost quiet content on Firefox while also lowering loud volume to a consistent level?

Background:
We are running multiple laptops with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (basic default apps install) and I am looking for a setting or application that will regulate the output of volume.  Anyone who has let YouTube autoplay while cooking/working/etc will notice that some content is too quiet and some videos are way too loud.

Looking into posts on this topic, the age pre-dates the popularity of deafening TikTok/YouTube shorts.  Other attempts to search the topic seems to assume I am creating content, which I am not.

Does anyone have recommendations for this family to save our tiny laptop speakers and headphones?  Thank you, in advance!
(First time poster)

Comment: How to normalize all audio output to speakers or headphones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically adjust the volume based on content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95716/automatically-adjust-the-volume-based-on-content)