# Cutoff max amplitude at a volume level

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, kde

I have tried multiple adjustments with alsamixer and pulseaudio, but none of these give the desired result I want.

The problem:

When I watch a youtube video on my laptop (sound output on my Laptop speaker), there are multiple instances when sound amplitude spikes (I don't know the technical term for that) eg. someone screams in a video. And that sound comes out Way too Loud!
When I reduce the master volume to make that Scream sound bearable, the normal video sound becomes almost inaudible.
This doesn't happen in every video, as some creators take care of these sudden sound amplitude spike, and they sort of keep the same amplitude the entire video.

I don't exactly know what I am looking for, I just wish the video is still audible, and somehow these sudden amplitude spikes (like screams) get cutoff on a tolerable value.

Please let me know if you need me to attach any config files.

I really appreciate your time. Thanks

---

PS:

This is one such [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDY70FTS0uQ) in which the a person screams. When I hear it on a laptop speaker, the scream is way too loud (on 75-80%) but this is the volume at which I can hear the rest of the normal video sound comfortably

Comment: Ok, now I got it, I thought you had a technical problem, but this guy really screams.  I know that what your are trying to accomplish (normalizing the sound while it is being played) can be done with some video/audio players, like VLC. However, I am not aware of a browser plugin or a general systemwide audio setting to accomplish this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of leveling/compressing the sound system-wide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31580/is-there-a-way-of-leveling-compressing-the-sound-system-wide)